# Having issues with spring cloud config server to read files/values from SVN through PROXY

Tags: cloud, config, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

In our microservices implementation, we are using spring cloud config to read config values - SVN as repository and accessing it through a proxy host.

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-config-server
  profiles:
    active: subversion
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
         svn:
           uri: <<<https://svn_host_name/directory/>>>
           username: <<<svu userID>>>
           password: <<<svu password>>>
           proxy:
             https: 
               host: <<<host IP of proxy>>>
               port: '80'
```

Following is the exception that I am getting:

```
2019-05-23 21:00:47.634 ERROR 11760 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot checkout repository] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.connect(SVNSocketFactory.java:162) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory._createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:122) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:92) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:282) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:461) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:398) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:386) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:863) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:699) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:118) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1049) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:189) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:184) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:809) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:26) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:11) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294) ~[svnkit-1.8.12.jar:na]
```

and the exception grows.

1. The scenario is working fine in local: property file kept in a local directory and being referred by cloud config project - works perfectly fine!
2. Have tried with http instead of https for proxy in application.yml [SVN is https always] but same exception.

Question:

I am sure that this is trying to connect to SVN repo but the issue seems to be is with proxy settings?!

Has anyone so far tried accessing SVN [or git] through a proxy , succeeded , faced similar issue by any chance?!

**UPDATE-1**

I am using Greenwich Release of spring cloud.

pom.xml (relevant) entries of cloud config server:

```
        <properties>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
           <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**UPDATE-2**

Used the same proxy IP in my TortoiseSVNtool under network option. With this, tortoise SVN is able to connect to the actual SVN URL, via the proxy IP.

It is not working in spring-cloud-config server. Not sure where I am lagging to cause this issue. Any inputs would be very much helpful and much appreciated.

As soon as I start the springboot project of client, it is trying to connect to cloudconfig server and the server throws exception mentioned above.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention the version of Spring Cloud you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick reply!!  I just have updated the question with required details.

Comment: Is there any setting in IDE where I can provide proxy IP there so that the config server is able to talk to eclipse?! Like kind of workaround..

Comment: Hi spencergibb, is there any other detail that is missing here?!You responded immediately initially but not now, so just thinking if there is some more information required which I am missing to provide.

Comment: Not that I know of. Greenwich.SR1 is the latest. It may be an issue with `org.tmatesoft.svnkit`.